# Angular 2 Array Sort Refactor

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, sorting, refactoring

This is my code:

```
let sortArray = array1.sort((a,b)=> a.id - b.id);
let array1Ids: number[] = [];   
sortArray.map(resp => array1Ids.push(resp .id));
```

I want to make this code more optimized, how do I refactor it?
**My goal is just to sort and get IDs.**

Comment: Don't use `map` for simple iteration. If you want to return a new array with just the IDs, then that's exactly what `map` already does `.map(resp => resp.id)`

Comment: And what do you mean by "more optimised"? Is there a performance problem here? Do you want this code shorter? Something else?

Comment: I want a shorter version

Comment: `let array1Ids: number[] = array1.map(x => x.id).sort((a, b) => a - b)`. But I'm not sure how this helps, really. This code will be compiled anyway, so you're probably going to minify it as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
let sortedArrayIds = array1.sort((a,b) => a.id - b.id).map(element => element.id);
```

If you use map you should always put it on the right side of an expression, because map RETURNS the new array. If you want just an iteration use forEach.